# scope of globals, locals, use with exec()

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time understanding the scope of `globals()`, `locals()` in Python. Consider the following code:

```
def f1(glob, loc):
    exec("b = 5", glob, loc)


f1(globals(), locals())
print(b + 1)
```

This passes `globals` and `locals` to `f1` where the variable `b = 5` is defined, and sure enough it's present after the function call in the main scope. The code correctly prints

```
6
```

To my surprise, when doing the same in the scope of a function, `f2` here, it fails:

```
def f1(glob, loc):
    exec("b = 5", glob, loc)


def f2():
    f1(globals(), locals())
    print(b + 1)


f2()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/q.py", line 10, in <module>
    f2()
  File "/tmp/q.py", line 7, in f2
    print(b + 1)
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Why is that? Is it possible to generalize `f1` to allow it to be called from `f2` as well?

Comment: This does not answer your specific question but I would recommend you look into using a [Class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Thanks @It_is_Chris for the reply. Not sure what problem looking at classes would solve. Could you be more specific?

Comment: He means that the question reads like you want the behaviour of a class, like "access `f1.b` from `f2`"

Comment: Outside of a function, `locals()` returns the same thing as `globals()` - the actual dict storing the global variables.  Inside a function, `locals()` creates and returns a new dict, containing a copy of the local variables (which, for the sake of efficiency, are not stored in a form directly representable as a Python object).  Changes to that dict have no effect; in particular you *cannot* create a new local variable by adding anything to the dict.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `locals` **is** the `globals` dict, because you're on a module level.

You can check that with `print(id(globals()), id(locals()))`

In your second example, `locals` is a different dict in the scope of the function.

So to make example 2 work, either use:

```
def f1(glob, loc):
    exec("b = 5", glob, loc)
def f2():
    f1(globals(), globals())
    print(b + 1)
f2()
```

or

```
def f1(glob, loc):
    exec("b = 5", glob, glob)
def f2(loc):
    f1(globals(), loc)
    print(b + 1)
f2(locals())
```

So this isn't really a matter of `exec()` but of in which scope you're calling `locals()`.

And ofc it's also a matter of what the code in exec does, because an assignment changes the scope of the name to the current (local) scope, unless `global`/`nonlocal` is involved. That's why `b=5` is executed in the local scope - except that in your first example, the "local" scope is the **global** scope.

---

Follow-up:

if you want to re-assign a value to `b` in `f2` you will need the `global` keyword:

```
def f1(glob, loc):
    exec("b = 5", glob, loc)
def f2():
    f1(globals(), globals())
    global b
    b += 1
    print(b + 1) # 7
f2()
```

Note that this has nothing to do with exec and passing around locals() / globals() - you can reduce it to this example, which would also fail w/o the `global` keyword (it would throw an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment` error).

```
b = 5
def f2():
    global b
    b += 1
    print(b + 1) # 7
f2()
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for this instructive answer! Any idea why `b += 1` won't work while `b + 1` does?

Comment: For the same reason I already mentioned: ``b += 1`` is an *assignment*, which changes the scope of ``b`` to the current scope, unless you use ``global/nonlocal`` - see updated answer. Think of writing it as ``b = b + 1`` - thus ``b`` must be known *in the current scope* before you can increment it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an explanation answer (jason's comment seems to be a good one though), but at work I've coded something that uses `exec`, and I've found `exec(code, globals())` is the only way that worked under all circumstances. Adding locals as an argument only caused various issues.

To adapt your code:

```
def f1(glob):
    exec("b = 5", glob)

def f2():
    f1(globals())
    print(b + 1)

f2()
# 6
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter, for the idea. I'm playing around with this now.

Comment: I found that this works, but `b += 1` doesn't. I'm flabbergasted.